# Run .sh script on Ubuntu without using terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, command-line

I'm using Ubuntu and I've created a simple script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /home/guilherme/pictures/*.jpg /home/guilherme/backup
```

When I run it on terminal typing the command "./script.sh" it works fine.

But when I try to click on this file outside the terminal, it opens my text editor to edit the lines of the script instead of opening the terminal and execute the commands.

I already gave the executable permission to this file, but it does not run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.sh` extension? Maybe Nautilus (or whatever file browser you're using) checks that.

Comment: yeah, I removed the extension and nothing happens

Comment: please send us `ls -la` of the script. check that the mountpoint is not mounted noexec.

Comment: This is surely not a programming question--please ask on SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 7):

You have to open `nautilus`, click File->Preferences **(OR)** Edit->Preferences,
check Behaviour tab, and select the option you prefer for Excutable Text Files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Open Nautilus .
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
3. Type `preferences`.
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Choose *Behavior* tab. Under *Executable Text Files* choose *Ask each time*.

You also need to mark your files as executables. To do that right click the `.sh` file, choose *Properties*, and under the *Permissions* tab check *Allow executing file as a program*.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your system settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts and add a custom shortcut.  For the command place the full path to the script.  Now you can run it without terminal

Comment: how if it needs password to run?

Answer (score 0):

Because i still see that a lot, for 20.04:

open Files then Preferences

[image: Here]

Then Behavior and check "Run them".Now you are able to double click .sh files and run (only if the file.sh is executable,right click in file.sh -> Permissions-> check "Allow executing file as a program").Now all your executables will run.If you dont want that for some scripts.sh,uncheck "Allow executing file as a program" and run it with 'bash yourscript.sh' from terminal.Working fine for me!

Answer (score -2):

in terminal type "chmod +x filepath". This will convert your sh file to an executable file that will run when you open it

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. It does not change it into a executable. Please delete your answer.